# Why does array traversal differ between php5 and php7

Tags: php-5.5, php-7.1

Consider some array:

```
$data = [
    "k0"=>"v0",
    "k1"=>"v1",
    "k2"=>"v2",
    "k3"=>"v3",
    "k4"=>"v4",
];
```

Traverse over array $data and print array $result_1

```
$result_1 = [];
while (key($data)) {
    $result_1[key($data)] = current($data);
    next($data);
}
print_r($result_1);

//Then perform the same operation in a function supplying the same array $data as argument 
//(mind that the internal pointer of $data is at the end):

traverse($data);

function traverse($arr){
    $result_2 = [];
    while (key($arr)) {
        $result_2[key($arr)] = current($arr);
        next($arr);
    }
    print_r($result_2);
}
```

If running the above code on php-5.5 $result_1 and $result_2 are the same:

```
//Array ( [k0] => v0 [k1] => v1 [k2] => v2 [k3] => v3 [k4] => v4 )
```

If running on php-7.1 $result_1 is the same as above but $result_2 is empty:

```
//Array ( )
```

> Why does array traversal differ between php-5.5 and php-7.1?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

The $var = []; syntax wasn't introduced in the initial release of php5.

Comment: the line `$result_2[key($arr)] = current($data);`, I suppose you meant `$result_2[key($arr)] = current($arr);`, right?

Comment: @ mishamosher - You are right, sure, updated the code

Comment: @vess you're interested more in an alternative code that produces the same output for every PHP version, or in a technical explanation about why this happens? The latter one I can't figure out still.

Comment: @mishamosher - Thanks. My code was developed on php-5.6 (old WAMP), but for some reason I had to migrate to php-7 on the production server. And it wouldn't run properly until I found this problem. Sure, changed the code and now it runs OK. So my question is _academic_ - did not find any explanation in the documentation...
maybe someone else will not loose a couple of hours to debug?

Comment: @vess oh, I see. It seems that the pointers operations have changed for arrays since PHP 7. A `reset($data)` before `traverse($data)` solves the issue. Also doing `$data2 = $data; traverse($data2);` keeps showing an empty array in PHP 7+. I've been playing around in 3v4l.org all this time and it all seems to be due to changes in array internal pointers. Only piece of official docs where I could find info that shows such changes in a different scenario is [this](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.foreach.by-ref)

Comment: I give up. I found nothing and this already consumed one hour of my effort. At least I know now that there is a difference with array internal pointers behaviour in PHP 7+ (:

Comment: @mishamosher - Thanks again! That's what I did - reset(). The other option is to use good old foreach(). 
As a matter of fact, php-7's behavior is as if you pass the array by reference (&$arr) which is not documented at least in php.net.
**Correction:** The array ($arr) is copied together with the value of its internal pointer.

Comment: This is extremely odd behaviour. Doing a `$data2 = $data; $data2["k0"] = "v0"; traverse($data2);` instead of `traverse($data);` fixes the PHP 7+ behaviour (now it shows the array values). Still found nothing in the docs. I feel too lazy as to checking PHP's source code only to find out specifically why this happens /:

Comment: @vess I've opened a bug report some time ago in [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77014), but it did not receive much attention from the PHP devs /:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've filed a bug in [PHP :: Bug #77014](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77014). The correct/intended behaviour is the one present in PHP 7+. I'm quoting the answer from `nikic@php.net`:

> The behavior is intended. Passing an array to a function does not
> change the position of the internal array pointer. I believe the PHP 5
> behavior was some kind of artifact of key() accepting the array by
> reference and triggering a separation there.
>
> If you'd like to make sure that you are iterating the array from the
> start rather than from the previous position of the internal array
> pointer, you can perform an explicit call to reset().
>
> (I'd recommend moving away from these functions entirely, if it is at
> all possible. If complex iteration patterns are involved,
> ArrayIterator may be an alternative.)

Mystery solved I guess.